# Listview title in Android

Tags: android, listview, tabs

My application has 2 tab. When I click tab 1 it will show the interface like google reader, like below

```
[  tab1  ][  tab2  ]
title 1
listview1 item
listview1 item
........
title 2
listview2 item
listview2 item
........
```

Each tab i use one activity. Please show me how to have interface like that. I just begin with android for 4 days :(. Thanks you!

ps: i can add 1 listview without title in tab1 but don't know how to add 2 listviews with 2 titles like that.

Comment: show as how you adding this listview ... in order to get title you have to add TextView, ListView, TextView, ListView (TextViews will be your titles) to your parent view (tab) try to build such layout in editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to add two listview with two titles, Just **add one listview with multiple sections header.**

Just look at this [Android – Sectioned Headers in ListViews](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/) example, Its nicely describe how to implement Sectioned Headers in ListViews.

And

[android-amazing-listview](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

[Jeff Sharkey's SeparatedListAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

[MergeAdapter by CommonsWare](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Thanks.

Comment: I need 2 listviews because data in them are different. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: for different data you have to manage two string array or list and then merge it and pass it to in one listview, so you don't have to manage two listviews.

Answer (score 0):

This should fit your needs:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title 1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title 2" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should overlap two listviews,both r invisible(set android:visibility = 'invisible') when u start the application but when u click on button tab1 list1 will visible and when u click on tab2 list1 will invisible and list 2 will be visible.You can use Relative layout to overlap the lists.You have to use flags to make both lists visible and invisible alternatively.